# Pattern for horizontal extensibility in domain models

Tags: php, oop, zend-framework, doctrine

I would like to be able to extend some of my models. A use case: I have a User module with a `User` model (and appropriate controllers + views). Then I have another module (say, Foo) from which I want to add a property to `User` (called Bar).

I use php, the Zend Framework and Doctrine, but I am thinking about a pattern, so not necessarily for these frameworks. It's more about the architecture than the implementation. Is this possible and what is the best pattern to follow?

I would like to have this kind of architecture, because otherwise you would create a `FooUser` model, with a property `user_id` and `foo`, causing to have joins (and for each extension, you have joins, hitting the performance badly). Is there a solution for this?

Comment: have you found good answer to your question?

Comment: Nope. The only idea for now is that `FooUser` and `BarUser` and query them all when you need them, possibly with Doctrine and a mapped super class. Module foo has one the user joins, module foo has one the user joins and your application must define the super user class knowing all the couplings :/